# Python Packages not installing via pip

Tags: python

I tried installing packages after reinstalling python, but these messages appeared

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\ljhub\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ljhub\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aouxvzul\\turtle\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ljhub\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aouxvzul\\turtle\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ljhub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ov8hdhie'
         cwd: C:\Users\ljhub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aouxvzul\turtle\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ljhub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aouxvzul\turtle\setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I could install cython and pypi, but nothing else with pip

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using python3, but installing a package that only supports python2.

```
14:11:09 $ python2 -c 'try: pass
> except Exception, e: pass'

14:11:20 $ python3 -c 'try: pass
except Exception, e: pass'
  File "<string>", line 2
    except Exception, e: pass
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python 2 is obsolete, so if possible you should seek out a modern approach. If that is infeasible, you can still try to run your application using Python 2, but the toolchain (things like `pip` itself) may not work for much longer in that environment.

---

**Clarification**

The only thing we can tell for sure from the details of the question is that `turtle`'s `setup.py` has some python2-specific code in it. But it's likely that the application itself does not support python3.